# Laptop will not hibernate when battery is critical

Tags: power-management, battery, hibernate

My laptop does not hibernate when the battery is critical.

I tried the suggestions in several posts with related or similar titles.  These included

1. ensuring that `pm-hibernate` works
2. modifying the settings in: `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power`
3. installing `laptop-mode-tools` and configuring `auto-hibernate.conf`

None of these things, however, solved the problem.  With the exception of trying to program a custom script to check the battery percentage every few minutes and hibernate when it gets lower than threshold, I am out of ideas for things to try.

I am running Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: which laptop model? i have seen this on Toshiba portege r830 failing to suspend when red battery light flashing